# El proyecto desaparece al ingresar a netbeans otra vez

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

El problema que tengo es que cuando creo un proyecto nuevo en netbeans y pego en la carpeta del proyecto las clases ya hechas, este solamente aparece en netbeans mientras este abierto, si lo cierro y vuelvo a abrirlo el proyecto desaparece.

Otro problema que tengo es que al copiar un proyecto a un USB e importarlo desde ahi en otra computadora me sale error por un combobox aunque en el proyecto original este no presente error alguno.

Tambien si alguien puede decirme porque al momento de abrir un proyecto hecho en netbeans en vez de aparecer con el simbolo de la taza de café, éste aparece como una carpeta normal se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Lo primero que puede pasar es que estes cerrando el proyecto por lo cual la misma desaparece. Tambien puede ser que hallas cambiado la ruta donde se almacena el mismo y esta no esta dentro de la ruta que por defecto tu IDE guarda los desarrollos. Debes revisar. De cualquier forma puedes importar tu proyecto.
Si quieres abrir tu proyecto para continuar el desarrollo en otra PC puedes exportar el mismo en archivo comprimido tipo zip por ejemplo y luego en la otra PC importarlo. Lo que si tienes es que estar pendiente que cuando importas el proyecto el se trae las configuraciones de la otra pc y

Comment: Cual es el error que te aparece ??

Comment: Los proyectos de netbeasn tienen una carpeta llamada `nbproject` lo más probable es que no tenga permisos de escritura y por ello al cerrar tu proyecto no se guarden las configuraciones que hiciste en el proyecto